# How to find out the exact operation that is posted to Dispatcher

Tags: wpf, dispatcher

Is there a way where we can find out which UI element has posted an operation to the Dispatcher queue which eventually throws the event ,`System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Hooks.OperationPosted`

**Update** : A private property `DispatcherOperation.Name` is showing what I need in the VS mouse-over in debugging mode. I just need to print this name to a logger for other debugging purposes. Is it possible to extract the `Name` dynamically.

Comment: Most useful was the observation that there's private `DispatcherOperation.Name` property by itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, while i give you a way to do it, i must warn you though, using reflection to get private or protected fields/properties/methods is never a good idea because first they are usually private for a reason and second of all if the signature or interface changes you code might break. But because you said it is just for debugging, this might be a valuable solution.

You can always use [Reflection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173183%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for these kind of things. First you need the Type and Instance of the object you want to read its private properties. Unfortunately i don't know if the Name you are looking for is a field or a property, but the overall procedure is similar. First get the property with [GetProperty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1y4s51k3.aspx) and then call [GetValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.propertyinfo.aspx) on the returned `PropertyInfo` object. You might want to cache the PropertyInfo object to gain some speed while debug. You also need to use the correct [BindingFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags.aspx) again i don't know exactly how the field/property is described so i can't give you the exact code, but from here it should be easy to figure out.

Hope that helps.

Comment: It's a private instance property (=> `GetProperty`), so two flags are needed: `NonPublic` and `Instance`

Comment: @dowhilefor, you are right, I could do that using      `type.GetProperty(propName, BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance )` and yes this is purely for debugging purposes and just to find out the who is keeping the UI busy for my XBAP is behaving a bit differently on XP and Win 7.